# CASE WHEN Formula - NetSuite

Tags: case, field, formula, netsuite, case-when

I'm trying to get results for a field with Formula (Text).
The idea is - if the subsidiary = A, then show field 1. If subsidiary = B, then show field B. (please see the formula below).
For some reason, I didn't get any results. Both fields are transaction column fields. When I'm testing only the fields (without formula - just the name of the field) they work.

Type of the Saved Search is: Transaction
Main Line is: False

Case when {subsidiary}='A' THEN {field1}
when {subsidiary}='B' THEN {fieild2} END

For the records which belong to the Subsidiary A field 2 is empty and for the Subsidiary B - field 1 is empty accordingly. Therefore I would like if
the Subsidiary is A to populate field 1 and if it's B to populate filed 2.
Can you please advise how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think the ELSE clause is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{subsidiary}` field is expecting the entire parent-child hierarchy for a match, so **'Honeycomb Holding Inc. : Honeycomb Mfg.'**.  You can use `{subsidiarynohierarchy} to match just the base subsidiary name (i.e, **Honeycomb Mfg.**) the transaction is in.  This formula should work:

```
case 
    when {subsidiarynohierarchy} = 'Honeycomb Mfg.' then {field1}  
    when {subsidiarynohierarchy} = 'test sub' then {field2}  
end
```

If no `ELSE` clause is provided and no match is found, it will return an empty result.

> For the records which belong to the Subsidiary A field 2 is empty and for the Subsidiary B - field 1 is empty accordingly.

If, as you mentioned, these fields are ONLY populated for the given subsidiary, then you could simplify the formula to this:

```
coalesce({field1}, {field2})
```

This will return the first non-null value so if subsidiary A has `field1` populated, it will return `field1`.  If subsidiary B has `field1` empty and `field2` is populated, it will return `field2`.

Comment: Dear Mike, Thank you very much. It is works perfect now. Thanks Again! Warm regards, Radoslav.

Answer (score 0):

Another way and making it more accurate, is to use {subsidiary.id}. The ID is the internal id of the subsidiary. I hate dealing with Text so I normally use internal id when needed, specially in CASE WHEN of a saved search.

If someone changes the name of the subsidiary or any other list field then the saved search will break.